# Soil moisture sensor problem

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I'm having a problem trying to run a bunch of code, using an "if" state which uses a variable which should get a value from a soil moisture sensor.

I'm using the sensor digitally, so it should just sense a value between the 2 discrete "0" and "1". However, even if I think my code is ok, it simply doesn't work, as the value is always "0"(default value is 0 for the global variable "sms" i use). The code I'm posting below is without an "else" state that is following the first "if". But my problem is inside the first "if" state. Please note that jumper wires are ok and also I've tried 3 different soil moisture sensors, two of which were brand new. Any ideas on what's wrong?

```cpp
//Start of program

char auth[] = "**************";
char ssid[] = "88888";
char pass[] = "99999999";

int Relay1 = D1;
int Relay2 = D2;
int val2;
float val3;
int sensor_pin = D7;
int pinValue;
SimpleTimer timer;
elapsedMillis timeElapsed;
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
NewPing sonar2(TRIGGER_PIN2, ECHO_PIN2, MAX_DISTANCE2);


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600); // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
  Blynk.begin(auth, ssid, pass);
  pinMode(Relay1, OUTPUT); //Setup Relay pin as output pin
  pinMode(Relay2, OUTPUT); //Setup Relay pin as output pin
  pinMode(sensor_pin, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(Relay1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Relay2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Relay1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Relay2, HIGH);
}


BLYNK_READ(V8)
{
  Blynk.virtualWrite(8, level);
}


BLYNK_WRITE(V1) {
  pinValue = param.asInt();
}




void loop()
{
  Blynk.run();
  timer.run();
  if (pinValue == 0)
  {
    some code here
    sms=digitalRead(sensor_pin);
    if ( sms == 0)
    {
      if (val2 <= 14)
      {
        code here          }
      else  
      {
        digitalWrite(Relay2, LOW); // Pump2 ON
        delay(500);

      }
    }
    else //(sms == 1)
    {
      some code here
    }
  }
```

[image: TE215 Moisture Sensor]

Comment: Do you mean the `sensor_pin` sensor is the issue? What sensor is it?  Does it need a pull-up resistor?  If you wire a logic HIGH to `sensor_pin` instead of the sensor, will it the code's logic work as expected?   I'd add a couple more `Serial.println()` statements to tell you some debug info.

Comment: @Dave X https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51YJV7u7mYL._SL1000_.jpg

Comment: @Dave X Also i when i formated the paste of code, i forgot the int sms=0; global variable.

Comment: Serial.println() lines were added. But sms value remains == 0.

Comment: `jumper wires are ok` ... what jumper wires?

Comment: reduce the code to the smallest code necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I mean physical wires which were used to connect sensor to arduino.

Comment: Code was reduced.

Comment: int sms=0;   This variable can NEVER EVER have any value between 0 and 1.  If you try to give it any value between the two it will end up with a 0.  Read up on what types of numbers an int can hold if you don't understand why.

Comment: There isn’t a `sms=...` anywhere in your code. Where would `sms` get any different value than the initial?

Comment: My mistake. I just erased it in order to reduce code. Now you can see where sms gets a value.

Comment: Sketch doesn't compile.

Comment: Obviously, since code is reduced....

Comment: What voltage does the sensor put out?  If you measure the D7 pin with a meter, is it ever above the 3 volt logic HIGH threshold to be interpreted as a 1?

Comment: I would put the sensor in sum very wet soil and have some code like this `loop(){Serial.println(digitalRead(sensor_pin));delay(500);}` and see what it says.  It might be that you have to tweak the pot on the board to set the sensitivity and it only goes high when it passes a certain value.